# Uikit Scrollspy custom Event

Tags: jquery, uikit, scrollspy

I'm having trouble getting a custom function with the scrollspy from the uiKit to work. I want to trigger a function when an object enters the screen.

I used the code from the uikit guide: 
http://getuikit.com/docs/scrollspy.html

This is my code:

jQuery

```
$('#object').on('uk.scrollspy.inview', function(){
    alert("It works");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="#object" data-uk-scrollspy>This is the object that should trigger the function</div>
```

I don't get any errors inf firebug and just don't know what is wrong since I can't find more documentation or anything and my jQuery skills are kind of limited. It would be great if anyone coul help me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some values to data-uk-scrollspy:

like this:
data-uk-scrollspy="{initcls:'uk-scrollspy-init-inview'}"

Comment: Unfortunately thats not what I was asking for and doesnt change anything about my problem. I want the function to trigger and not to use the standard scollspy functionality like adding a class.

Answer (score 0):

Since UIkit v2.13 November 2014 event name changed from "uk.scrollspy.inview" to "inview.uk.scrollspy"

So you should use another event name

```
$('#object').on('inview.uk.scrollspy', function(){
    alert("It works");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add data-uk-scrollspy="" to the selector on HTML for example:

```
<h2 id="works" data-uk-scrollspy="">Heading</h2>
```

Then just use this:

```
UIkit.util.on('#works', 'inview', function () {
    alert("It works");
});
```